# Pandas: How to map the list of dictionary in a column as a new row

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

The dataframe which is in below format has to be converted like "op_df",

```
ip_df=pd.DataFrame({'class':['I','II','III'],'details':[[{'sec':'A','assigned_to':'tom'},{'sec':'B','assigned_to':'sam'}],[{'sec':'B','assigned_to':'joe'}],[]]})
ip_df:
     class    details
0    I        [{'sec':'A','assigned_to':'tom'},{'sec':'B','assigned_to':'sam'}]
1    II       [{'sec':'B','assigned_to':'joe'}]
2    III      []
```

The required output dataframe is suppose to be,

```
 op_df:
      class sec assigned_to 
 0    I     A   tom    
 1    I     B   sam
 2    II    B   joe
 3    III   NaN NaN
```

How to change each dictionaries of "details" column as a new row with keys of the dictionary as column name and value of the dictionary as its respective column value?

I have tried with,

```
ip_df.join(ip_df['details'].apply(pd.Series))
```

whereas, I am unable to frame like "op_df".

Comment: Do you have any control over the initial datastructure?  There's nothing in `class` that is tying together the details.  It's purely positional which is very brittle.

Comment: I agree. My answer below depends completely on the 'inception' style hierarchy in the data. Very brittle, and will break as soon as the data structure changes slightly.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are better ways to do it, but I had to deconstruct your details list and create your dataframe as follows:

```
dict_values = {'class':['I','II','III'],'details':[[{'sec':'A','assigned_to':'tom'},{'sec':'B','assigned_to':'sam'}],[{'sec':'B','assigned_to':'joe'}],[]]}

all_values = []

for cl, detail in zip(dict_values['class'], dict_values['details']):

    if len(detail) > 0:
        for innerdict in detail:
            row = {'class': cl}
            for innerkey in innerdict.keys():
                row[innerkey] = innerdict[innerkey]
            all_values.append(row)
    else:
        row = {'class': cl}
        all_values.append(row)

op_df = pd.DataFrame(all_values)
```